# Скопируровать файл из проекта JAVA MAVEN "А" в проект JAVA MAVEN "Б" на этапе BUILD

Tags: java, maven, jar, build

Как можно скопируровать файл из проекта JAVA MAVEN "Проект А.jar" в проект JAVA MAVEN "Проект Б" на этапе BUILD.

```
Проект А
- Folder1
- Folder2
   - Folder3
      - file1.xml // Этот файл нужно скопировать
- Folder4
- pom.xml

----------------------------------------------

Проект Б
- Folder1
- Folder2
- Folder3
- Folder4
- target
   - Folder1
   - Folder2
      - Folder3
         - file1.xml // Здесь мы должны скопировать файл
   - Folder4
- pom.xml
```

---

```
Проект A pom.xml

project>
   <groupId>com.commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1</version>
</project>
```

---

```
Проект Б pom.xml

project>
   <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
   <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1</version>

    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.1</version>
       </dependency> 
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: проекты это подмодули одного и того же проекта?

Comment: Почему его просто ручками не скопировать, для чего нужна подобная автоматизация ?

Comment: Проект А - это отдельный JAR в котором есть file1.xml.
Проект Б - это отдельный проект в котором нужно скопировать файл file1.xml из Проект А.JAR

Comment: Почему его просто ручками не скопировать - для того чтобы о другий проекты использовапи тот же файл конфигурации. И чтоб изменение сделалось только в одном месте.

Comment: Чтобы все тут поняли, ты это `.jar` (проект А) как-нибудь "импрортируешь" в проекте B?

Comment: Я добавил детали выше. Я импортирую проект A как Maven зависимость